# NullPointer of Bitmap in Draw method

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to draw a bitmap on the canvas. The bitmap is returning null, however I don't understand why. I've read into the documentation for Bitmap and decodeResources. It seems like the drawable is returning null since decode can't find it. I've attempted to use debug sessions but I am not getting very far.

Please advise on the null exception.

Faulty Class:

```
public class SnapShot extends Activity {

private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawIcon(canvas);    
}

private void drawIcon(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.buttongreen); //this is line 36
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, paint);
}
```

}

Stack trace:

```
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.game.SnapShot.drawIcon(SnapShot.java:36)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.game.SnapShot.draw(SnapShot.java:29)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.game.onDraw(AugmentedView.java:77)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-01 09:24:30.638: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Need more info, perhaps set a breakpoint on line 36 and see what the null object is.

Comment: @Souvlaki using the debugger it tells me that ViewRoot.draw(boolean) is returning null. From reading how decodeResource works if the int id of the bitmap cannot be found it returns null. However using R.drawable format should return the id right? It compiles so I would assume it can find the drawable fine in the method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the drawIcon(Canvas canvas) method inside a view, then you should have a context to call getResource().

Eg:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.buttongreen);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, paint);
```

Comment: Very good thank you. For anyone else I had to pass the context from the actual activity since this class is an overlay..so try "draw(Canvas canvas, Context context)" and it will work